# How to calculate percentage area cover using Focal Statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster

I am trying to produce raster outputs in ArcGIS for later use in MaxEnt to model species distributions, and want to produce variables with statistics on the percentage cover of different habitat polygons (i.e. woodland) and linear features (i.e treelines or hedgerows) at different spatial scales (e.g within a moving analysis window).

I have a fairly rudimentary understanding of ArcGIS. I feel that Focal Statistics tool should be able to achieve what i want if i convert my layer inputs to raster format, however percent is not listed as an option in the Statistics field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the mean with focal stat will give you the percentage of cells in the neighbourhood if you apply it on binary (0/1) images.

This work because you can assume that the pixels have the same size.

For lines, you can also use the [line density](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000000t000000.htm) tool, which works directly from the vector polylines.

EDIT: based on the comments

The binary image can be created with raster calculator :

```
Con(IsNull("raster"), 0,1)
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would i create a binary raster with zero values rather than nodata?

Comment: Use [`Not IsNull(my raster)`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Is_Null/009z000000m8000000/).

Comment: ~IsNull(my raster)